# Material-UI XGrid multiple select with checkbox 'select all rows checkbox' to select filtered rows only?

Tags: material-ui

Is it possible to select only filtered rows with select all rows checkbox on XGrid?
Default behaviour is to select all rows regardless of filtering status...

Answer (score 0):

You can build a custom filter function.

```
const applyFilters = (rows, query, filters) => {
  return rows.filter((row) => {
    let matches = true;

    Object.keys(filters).forEach((key) => {
      const value = filters[key];

      if (value && row[key] !== value) {
        matches = false;
      }
    });

    return matches;
  });
};
```

And you can use the function in the component.

```
  // set state for selected rows
  const [selectedRows, setSelectedRows] = useState([]);
  // define some filters
  const [filters, setFilters] = useState({
    hasConditionA: null,
    hasConditionB: null
  });


  const handleSelectFilteredRows = (event, value) => {
    const updatedFilters = {
      ...filters,
      hasConditionA: null,
      hasConditionB: null
    };

    // If it doesn't have specific conditions, select all
    if (value !== 'all') {
      updatedFilters[value] = true;
    }

    setFilters(updatedFilters);
    setSelectedRows([]);
  };

  // you can select all rows as well
  const handleSelectAllRows = (event) => {
    setSelectedRows(event.target.checked
      ? rows.map((row) => row.id)
      : []);
  };

  const filteredRows = applyFilters(rows, query, filters);
  const selectedSomeRows = selectedRows.length > 0 && selectedRows.length < rows.length;
  const selectedAllRows = selectedRows.length === rows.length;

  ...
    <Table>
      <TableHead>
        <TableRow>
          <TableCell padding="checkbox">
            <Checkbox
              checked={selectedAllRows}
              indeterminate={selectedSomeRows}
              onChange={handleSelectAllRows}
            />
          </TableCell>
          <TableCell>
            Name
          </TableCell>
          <TableCell>
            Field A
          </TableCell>
          <TableCell>
            Field B
          </TableCell>
        </TableRow>
      </TableHead>
      <TableBody>
        // Render the filtered rows only
        {filteredRows.map((row) => {
          const isRowSelected = selectedRows.includes(row.id);

          return (
            <TableRow
              hover
              key={row.id}
              selected={isRowSelected}
            >
              <TableCell padding="checkbox">
                <Checkbox
                  checked={isRowSelected}
                  onChange={(event) => handleSelectOneRow(event, row.id)}
                  value={isRowSelected}
                />
              </TableCell>
              <TableCell>
                Field A
              </TableCell>
              <TableCell>
                Field B
              </TableCell>
            </TableRow>
          );
        })}
      </TableBody>
    </Table>
  ...
```

Hope this would help you.

Comment: [XGrid](https://material-ui.com/api/x-grid) is component I was asking about, it seems that in v4.0.0.0-alpha.19 version there is no support for selecting only filtered rows  but it is possible to calculate filtered only rows by using props.state.visibleRows.visibleRows. While your answer is not relevant it might be useful to someone.