# React Material-UI Column Search Selection

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I am currently using Material-UI data tables and have a search routine that is similar to this [Codesandbox example](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-ui-table-search-demo-x3viu?file=/demo.tsx), which is just searching on the `Name/Food` column alone.

My current code is as follows:

```
const [filterFn, setFilterFn] = useState({ fn: items => { return items; } })

const handleSearch = e => {
    let target = e.target;
    setInput(target.value)
    setFilterFn({
        fn: items => {
            if (target.value == "")
                return items;
            else                    
                return items.filter(x => x.name.toLowerCase().includes(target.value))
        }
    })
}
```

And within my current search input, I am calling `handleSearch` as follows:

```
            <Controls.Input
                id="name"
                label="Search Name"
                value={input}
                autoFocus={true}
                className={classes.searchInput}
                InputProps={{
                    startAdornment: (<InputAdornment position="start">
                        <Search />
                </InputAdornment>)
                }}
                onChange={handleSearch}
            />
```

With this, I now need a means of being able to search on any of the columns within this data table, i.e, `Calories`, `Carbs` or `Protein` and not just on the `Food`.

I was thinking of proving the user a drop-down selection list of all the available columns and then being able to use that column to perform their search but unsure how to achieve this as new to material-ui.

Can anyone please assist with how to achieve this or possibly point me to examples or other packages that still use material-ui as keen to get this going.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the similar case.
[Material-UI XGrid multiple select with checkbox 'select all rows checkbox' to select filtered rows only?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66040790/material-ui-xgrid-multiple-select-with-checkbox-select-all-rows-checkbox-to-se/66041802#66041802)

And if you can look through the `applyFilter` function, then I am pretty sure that you could implement what you want by comparing `searchedVal` inside a loop of keys.

That's an idea for it.

So in your case, I'd like to code this way.

```
const requestSearch = (originalRows: [], searchedVal: string): [] => {
  return originalRows.filter((row) => {
    let matches = true;

    if (searchedVal) {
      const properties = ['Name', 'Calories', 'Carbs', 'Protein'];
      // include keys what you want to search

      let containsVal = false;

      properties.forEach((property) => {
        if (originalRows[property].toLowerCase().includes(searchedVal.toLowerCase())) {
          containsVal = true;
        }
      });

      if (!containsVal) {
        matches = false;
      }
    }

    return matches;
  });
};
```

I believe this is not tricky for Material-UI, just a search function in JavaScript.