# React Search or Filter data based on multiple input

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I am stuck in a problem where i am implementing a search field in which a user can type into multiple field and it will give results depending on those results i.e Name, email etc.

Data object:

```
[
  {
   name:lorem,
   email:lorem@example.com
  }
]
```

Suppose there are two search fields one for name and other for email, and if user type in both fields or one field, it should return an array with matching properties.

```
i.e 
searchInput ={
   name:Lorem,
   email:lorem@example.com
}

result:
   [
      {
       name:lorem,
       email:lorem@example.com
      }
    ]
```

i am storing the input values like this

```
const [searchInput, setSearchInput] = useState<any>({});
const handleChange = (event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    const { name, value } = event.target;

    setSearchInput({ ...searchInput, [name]: value });
  };

<input type="text" onChange={handleChange} name="email">Name</input>
```

I have tried multiple answer here but so far not getting the results that i want.

I have solved the search issues but now i am facing this.
******** Another Issue ********

```
const [users, setUsers] = useState<any>([...])
 const tempArr = [...users];
    const data = tempArr.filter((e: any) =>
      Object.keys(e).some(
        (key) =>
          e[key] &&
          searchInput[key] &&
          e[key]
            .toString()
            .toLowerCase()
            .includes(searchInput[key].toLowerCase())
      )
    );

    if (data.length) {
      setUsers(data);
    }
```

so the search is working as expected but now i am losing the original data and i have to reload the page to get the original data. so is there any way to filter the data without losing the original data.

**Solution:**

```
const [searchInput, setSearchInput] = useState<any>(null); // change initial state to null

// Fetch the data if searchInput is null
useEffect(() => {
    if (!searchInput) {
       // Make the api call to fetch data
    }
  }, [searchInput]);

  //   Changes in input handler
  const handleChange = (event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    const { name, value } = event.target;

    if (!!value) {
      setSearchInput({ ...searchInput, [name]: value });
    } else {
      setSearchInput(null); // set null if there isn't any search input.
    }
  };
```

*The search function stays the same.*

Comment: where is you email input handle?

Comment: @MWO updated the question.

Comment: @callmeizaz Refer to this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68949919/react-material-ui-column-search-selection/68950600#68950600

Answer (score 0):

You can try one of these:

- https://fusejs.io/
- https://github.com/bvaughn/js-search

// Ignore below

Try using `useEffect` hook

```
useEffect(() => {
  // I suppose
  loadData(searchInput["email"], searchInput["name"])
}, [searchInput])
```

Or be more clear with the results you want

Comment: I am not talking about loading data on render, i am basically asking for a search function.

Comment: Ok, you are trying to do a search on the client side

Answer (score 0):

> ...the search is working as expected but now I am losing the original
> data and I have to reload the page to get the original data.

You are losing state fidelity because you are overwriting it with the result of filtered values.

```
const [users, setUsers] = useState<any>([...]);
const tempArr = [...users];
const data = tempArr.filter((e: any) =>
  Object.keys(e).some(
    (key) =>
      e[key] &&
      searchInput[key] &&
      e[key]
        .toString()
        .toLowerCase()
        .includes(searchInput[key].toLowerCase())
  )
);

if (data.length) {
  setUsers(data); // <-- overwrites the state!!
}
```

> So is there any way to filter the data without losing the original
> data.

Yes, don't overwrite the source of truth in state. Use the saved `users` state array and filter state values to *derive* the rendered result. In other words, do the filtering inline when rendering your `users` array to the UI.

Example:

```
users.filter((user: any) =>
  Object.keys(user).some((key) =>
    e[key] &&
    searchInput[key] &&
    e[key]
      .toString()
      .toLowerCase()
      .includes(searchInput[key].toLowerCase()
  ))
).map(user => (
  // ... returned JSX for `user` value
))
```

Comment: you're right the setState is overwriting my original data. And your answer is right but i don't want to return the JSX from the function so the solution i came up with is to use useEffect hook to fetch data again when the search input is null and it's working perfectly. I will add the solution and if there's is better way please suggest me that.